# How come there are 5 Workplace questions in the hot list?

Tags: support, hot-questions

Over the last two days I've observed that there are 5 Workplace questions in the [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) list.

Given that list contains 100 questions and there are more than 100 sites in SE network, equal distribution would mean less than one question per site in that list. How come Workplace presence is 5x more than average? What purpose does this serve?

Is there a [danger](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/conversation/cultural-clash) that this amount will blow up to, say, [10 questions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HNqJur7RXY)?

Is there some sort of technically enabled limit, like "no more than 5 questions from Workplace in the list"? If yes, what [bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222993/165773) could happen if that limit is dropped to 1 or 2 or 3 questions?

Related questions:

- at MSO: [“SO questions are penalized” in the hot list - how does that work, can it be done for other site(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226304/165773)
- [Do we want such a "handicap" (whatever it means) for Workplace questions in the hot list?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2514)

Comment: I count 10 TWP questions out of the 100 right now. WHAT DID YOU DO?

Comment: ["human interaction... doesn't blow up like a balloon"](http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html "Clay Shirky: 'A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy'")

Comment: @Shog9 you may consider clicking word "danger" in the question text

Comment: FWIW, there are seven questions right now in the list: [1](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20883/168),
[2](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20769/168),
[3](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20975/168),
[4](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20905/168),
[5](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20843/168),
[6](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20893/168),
[7](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20876/168). In comparison, Stack Overflow has 3 (that's t-h-r-e-e)... no wonder it's [priority -17](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220325/165773) to them, with such a protection

Comment: for the record: "That just tells me that TWP needs a handicap... with 100+ sites, none of them should have more than a handful in the list at once" ([Shog9](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14505373#14505373 "in Workplace 2014 Election chat"))

Comment: related: [Does Stack Exchange record when particular question enters and leaves hot list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238445/165773)

Comment: related conversation in Tavern chat: [follow-up to "How come there are 5 Workplace questions in the hot list?"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/follow-up-to-how-come-there-are-5-workplace-questions-in-the-hot-list) _"Shog referred to my meta post about 5 TWP questions in hot list to tell us his story of penalization but when I check it now I see even more than I complained about - 6. Yeah. Insufficiently. Let's call it that way..."_