# Do we want such a "handicap" (whatever it means) for Workplace questions in the hot list?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

[How come there are 5 Workplace questions in the hot list?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/how-come-there-are-5-workplace-questions-in-the-hot-list)

When discussing above question in elections chat, [Shog noted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14505373#14505373):

> **...TWP needs a handicap
>
>   with 100+ sites, none of them should have more than a handful in the list at once**

Do we want to establish a handicap mentioned above, for the reasons stated above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *really* dislike the idea of Workplace becoming a specialized Stack Exchange site. The more things which are specific to here the more problems we are going to have longer term.

For this reason, I would be opposed to this idea.

Comment: you mean, you want Workplace to be presented in the just list like other sites? Note I don't know how special are mentioned "handicaps" (for some reasons SE team seems to prefer to keep hot list features obscure) - SO certainly has one, and if memory serves Code Golf or Bitcoin had these too

Comment: @gnat I don't want this site to have lots of specific features relative to most SE sites. For example, we already have unique protection rules, this would be another unique thing, etc.

Comment: thanks! I think I understand now. If this would be really a unique feature (I can't tell, since I don't know if it is), I would likely be opposed to it as well, for the very reason you point out

Comment: @gnat yeah, I guess my thoughts would change if lots of other sites have their own "filters" or adjustments. At that point I'd emphatically agree :)

Comment: FWIW I was just [reminded at MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228199/165773) that there's "per-site traffic adjustment" that seems (sorry for being vague but SE team somehow doesn't make it clearer) to be individual for each site, somehow (again, sorry for being vague...) depending on the traffic. So, there is a (vague...) chance that Shog refers to some unknown to us feature which works for every site, possibly (vague...) in a non-specialized way